# How to properly handler error from contract call with go etheruem

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I am writing an application with https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum

Basically I am trying to check a given smart contract address is erc20 or not. I am calling getBalance, getSymbol... methods. My question is, how do I differentiate real error and system failure? By real error I mean for example, when smart contract doesn't have getBalance method, the returned value isn't valid types.. etc. So far I got few like:

- abi: cannot marshal in to go slice: offset...
- Error: execution reverted: xxx, function selector not found : xxx

All of them return different error string. By system failure I mean, network reset, unhealthy host.. etc. Is there a list to list down all errors go-ethereum could throw so that in my application I can differentiate them from system failures which should be retried?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle errors from contract calls with Go Ethereum is to use try/catch blocks when calling the functions. You can also use a logging service like Sentry to capture any errors that occur in your app, which can help you differentiate between real errors and system failures. Additionally, you should ensure that your application is well tested and that any expected errors are caught and handled properly.

Comment: chat gpt answer